# Animate slideDown() and slideUp() on minicart in header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slide

I tried to make my mini-cart (exactly like on this page http://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/) animated when the user hovers like here https://www.foodspring.de/ but I don't know how I can do this? Does anybody know an answer? I've tried it with `slideUp` and `slideDown` but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: please share the code you have tried, also consider using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: please ignore my edit, i messed up

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use CSS as a solution for this problem.

A little example for displaying the list when you are hovering the cart title:
HTML:

```
<a class="cart">
    <span>Cart title</span>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.cart ul {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    margin-top: -10px;
    display: none;
}

.cart:hover ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    display: block
}
```

As you can see, the list with products is only showing when you `:hover` the `.cart`

Answer (score 0):

like this?
edit: not sure why the content css isn't shown correctly, it supposed to display the cart icon.

```css
.count:after{
  content:"\f291"
  }
.count:hover{
  color:green
  }
```

```html
<div>
 <span class="count"></span>
  </div>
```